How to verify if Outlook sends SubmitMessage to my transport provider?
I have a MAPI C++ plugin which connect to outlook.
Is there a way where I can confirm or verify if outlook is unable to send SubmitMessage() call to my transport provider? Because in normal scenario when someone composes new email and clicks send button I do receive call in SubmitMessage() function of my transport provider. But at time when outlook stucks/hangs, I don't receive any such call in my SubmitMessage().
I wanted a way to prove it that Outlook is not sending that message to transport provider.
Is there a tool where I can check that out? Tried ProcMon But it's not that much useful.
Tried API Monitor, but it didn't help

What exactly do you mean by "But at time when outlook stucks/hangs"? When exactly does that happen?

When we have so many persona created, which outlook treats as separate account added in primary account. Outlook keep on syncing the persona accounts every 1 minute even if the Send Receive group setting is set for 30 minutes. And this is the time when Outlook hangs.

So the problem is that you add too many accounts to the profile?
